# Intelligently calculating chart tick positions

Tags: python, math, graph

Whatever I'm using matplotlib, Open-Flash-Charts or other charts frameworks I always end needing to find a way to set x/y scales limits and intervals since builtins are not enough smart (or not at all...)

just try this in pylab (ipyhton -pylab) to understand what I mean:

```
In [1]: a, b, x = np.zeros(10), np.ones(10), np.arange(10)

In [2]: plot(x, a); plot(x, b)
```

you'll see just and empty frame grid hiding the 2 horizontal lines under it's its top and bottom borders.

I wonder if there is some algorithm around (that I can port to python) to set smartly top and bottom y limits and steps and also calculate every how many values show the x thick.

For example, let's say I have 475 measures as `(datetime, temperature)` as `(x, y)` with

```
2011-01-15 10:45:00 < datetime < 2011-01-17 02:20:00
```

(one every 5 minutes) and

```
26.5 < temperature < 28.3
```

My suggestion for this particular case could be to set:

> `26.4 <= y_scale <= 28.4` with a thick every `.2`

and a tick on `x_scale` every 12 items (once per hour).

But what about if I have just 20 measures over 20 days with  `-21.5 < temperature < 38.7`, and so on? Is there a standardized method around?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is what I've used for years which is simple and works well enough. Forgive me for it being C but translating to Python shouldn't be difficult.

The following function is needed and is from Graphic Gems volume 1.

```
double NiceNumber (const double Value, const int Round) {
  int    Exponent;
  double Fraction;
  double NiceFraction;

  Exponent = (int) floor(log10(Value));
  Fraction = Value/pow(10, (double)Exponent);

  if (Round) {
    if (Fraction < 1.5) 
      NiceFraction = 1.0;
    else if (Fraction < 3.0)
      NiceFraction = 2.0;
    else if (Fraction < 7.0)
      NiceFraction = 5.0;
    else
      NiceFraction = 10.0;
   }
  else {
    if (Fraction <= 1.0)
      NiceFraction = 1.0;
    else if (Fraction <= 2.0)
      NiceFraction = 2.0;
    else if (Fraction <= 5.0)
      NiceFraction = 5.0;
    else
      NiceFraction = 10.0;
   }

  return NiceFraction*pow(10, (double)Exponent);
 }
```

Use it like in the following example to choose a "nice" start/end of the axis based on the number of major ticks you wish displayed. If you don't care about ticks you can just set it to a constant value (ex: 10).

```
      //Input parameters
  double AxisStart = 26.5;
  double AxisEnd   = 28.3;
  double NumTicks  = 10;

  double AxisWidth;
  double NewAxisStart;
  double NewAxisEnd;
  double NiceRange;
  double NiceTick;

    /* Check for special cases */
  AxisWidth = AxisEnd - AxisStart;
  if (AxisWidth == 0.0) return (0.0);

    /* Compute the new nice range and ticks */
  NiceRange = NiceNumber(AxisEnd - AxisStart, 0);
  NiceTick = NiceNumber(NiceRange/(NumTicks - 1), 1);

    /* Compute the new nice start and end values */
  NewAxisStart = floor(AxisStart/NiceTick)*NiceTick;
  NewAxisEnd = ceil(AxisEnd/NiceTick)*NiceTick;

  AxisStart = NewAxisStart; //26.4
  AxisEnd = NewAxisEnd;     //28.4
```

Comment: the more I use this the more I find it really smart, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

I report here my python version of above C code if it may be of any help for someone:

```py
import math


def nice_number(value, round_=False):
    '''nice_number(value, round_=False) -> float'''
    exponent = math.floor(math.log(value, 10))
    fraction = value / 10 ** exponent

    if round_:
        if fraction < 1.5:
            nice_fraction = 1.
        elif fraction < 3.:
            nice_fraction = 2.
        elif fraction < 7.:
            nice_fraction = 5.
        else:
            nice_fraction = 10.
    else:
        if fraction <= 1:
            nice_fraction = 1.
        elif fraction <= 2:
            nice_fraction = 2.
        elif fraction <= 5:
            nice_fraction = 5.
        else:
            nice_fraction = 10.

    return nice_fraction * 10 ** exponent


def nice_bounds(axis_start, axis_end, num_ticks=10):
    '''
    nice_bounds(axis_start, axis_end, num_ticks=10) -> tuple
    @return: tuple as (nice_axis_start, nice_axis_end, nice_tick_width)
    '''
    axis_width = axis_end - axis_start
    if axis_width == 0:
        nice_tick = 0
    else:
        nice_range = nice_number(axis_width)
        nice_tick = nice_number(nice_range / (num_ticks - 1), round_=True)
        axis_start = math.floor(axis_start / nice_tick) * nice_tick
        axis_end = math.ceil(axis_end / nice_tick) * nice_tick

    return axis_start, axis_end, nice_tick
```

use as:

```
>>> nice_bounds(26.5, 28.3)
(26.4, 28.4, 0.2)
```

---

Also add a javascript porting:

```
function nice_number(value, round_){
    //default value for round_ is false
    round_ = round_ || false;
    // :latex: \log_y z = \frac{\log_x z}{\log_x y}
    var exponent = Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.log(10));
    var fraction = value / Math.pow(10, exponent);

    if (round_)
        if (fraction < 1.5)
            nice_fraction = 1.
        else if (fraction < 3.)
            nice_fraction = 2.
        else if (fraction < 7.)
            nice_fraction = 5.
        else
            nice_fraction = 10.
    else
        if (fraction <= 1)
            nice_fraction = 1.
        else if (fraction <= 2)
            nice_fraction = 2.
        else if (fraction <= 5)
            nice_fraction = 5.
        else
            nice_fraction = 10.

    return nice_fraction * Math.pow(10, exponent)
}

function nice_bounds(axis_start, axis_end, num_ticks){
    //default value is 10
    num_ticks = num_ticks || 10;
    var axis_width = axis_end - axis_start;

    if (axis_width == 0){
        axis_start -= .5
        axis_end += .5
        axis_width = axis_end - axis_start
    }

    var nice_range = nice_number(axis_width);
    var nice_tick = nice_number(nice_range / (num_ticks -1), true);
    var axis_start = Math.floor(axis_start / nice_tick) * nice_tick;
    var axis_end = Math.ceil(axis_end / nice_tick) * nice_tick;
    return {
        "min": axis_start,
        "max": axis_end,
        "steps": nice_tick
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `Math.log10()` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my python code to automatically calculate ticks, it needs the range of data and the max number of ticks.

For example:

```
auto_tick([-120, 580], max_tick=10, tf_inside=False)
Out[224]: array([-100.,   -0.,  100.,  200.,  300.,  400.,  500.])
auto_tick([-120, 580], max_tick=20, tf_inside=False)
Out[225]: array([-100.,  -50.,   -0.,   50.,  100.,  150.,  200.,  250.,  300., 350.,  400.,  450.,  500.,  550.])
```

Below is the Python code of the function

```py
def auto_tick(data_range, max_tick=10, tf_inside=False):
    """
    tool function that automatically calculate optimal ticks based on range and the max number of ticks
    :param data_range:   range of data, e.g. [-0.1, 0.5]
    :param max_tick:     max number of ticks, an interger, default to 10
    :param tf_inside:    True/False if only allow ticks to be inside
    :return:             list of ticks
    """
    data_span = data_range[1] - data_range[0]
    scale = 10.0**np.floor(np.log10(data_span))    # scale of data as the order of 10, e.g. 1, 10, 100, 0.1, 0.01, ...
    list_tick_size_nmlz = [5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]   # possible tick sizes for normalized data in range [1, 10]
    tick_size_nmlz = 1.0     # initial tick size for normalized data
    for i in range(len(list_tick_size_nmlz)):                 # every loop reduces tick size thus increases tick number
        num_tick = data_span/scale/list_tick_size_nmlz[i]     # number of ticks for the current tick size
        if num_tick > max_tick:                               # if too many ticks, break loop
            tick_size_nmlz = list_tick_size_nmlz[i-1]
            break
    tick_size = tick_size_nmlz * scale             # tick sizse for the original data
    ticks = np.unique(np.arange(data_range[0]/tick_size, data_range[1]/tick_size).round())*tick_size    # list of ticks

    if tf_inside:     # if only allow ticks within the given range
        ticks = ticks[ (ticks>=data_range[0]) * (ticks<=data_range[1])]

    return ticks
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's the version of [@uesp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439599/uesp) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955179/1056679) in TypeScript / JavaScript ES6:

```js
function niceNumber(value: number, round = false) {

  const exponent = Math.floor(Math.log10(value));
  const fraction = value / Math.pow(10, exponent);

  let niceFraction: number;

  if (round) {
    if (fraction < 1.5) {
      niceFraction = 1.0;
    } else if (fraction < 3.0) {
      niceFraction = 2.0;
    } else if (fraction < 7.0) {
      niceFraction = 5.0;
    } else {
      niceFraction = 10.0;
    }
  } else {
    if (fraction <= 1.0) {
      niceFraction = 1.0;
    } else if (fraction <= 2.0) {
      niceFraction = 2.0;
    } else if (fraction <= 5.0) {
      niceFraction = 5.0;
    } else {
      niceFraction = 10.0;
    }
  }

  return niceFraction * Math.pow(10, exponent);

}

export function calcTicks(minValue: number, maxValue: number, ticksCount: number) {

  const range = niceNumber(maxValue - minValue);

  const tickValue = niceNumber(range / (ticksCount - 1), true);

  const ticks: number[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < ticksCount; i++) {
    ticks.push(minValue + tickValue * i);
  }

  return ticks;

}
```

However, `calcTicks()` function here returns an array of ticks instead of start and end bounds.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl version that offers options of working on axis start and end, (or derive this form list of data points), with functions to produce (start, end, tick size) or a list of tick points

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

print join("--",niceTicks(minmax([34,6,-7,15]),5));


#given a list of data (as an array or arrayref, return minimum and maximum)
sub minmax{
   my @list=@_;
   @list=@{$list[0]} if (ref $list[0]);
   my $max=my $min = shift @list;;
   foreach my $v (@list){
      $max=$v if $max<$v;
      $min=$v if $min>$v;   
   }
   return ($min,$max)
}

# niceTicks
# takes minimum value, maximum value and number of desired ticks;
# returns list of ticks
sub niceTicks{
   my ($axisStart,$axisEnd,$nTicks)=@_;
   ($axisStart,$axisEnd,my $tick)=niceAxis($axisStart,$axisEnd,$nTicks);
   my @tickList=($axisStart);
   push @tickList,$tickList[-1]+$tick while ($tickList[-1]<=$axisEnd);
   return @tickList;
}

# niceAxis
# takes minimum value, maximum value and number of desired ticks;
# returns nice axis start, axis end and gap between ticks
sub niceAxis{   
   my ($axisStart,$axisEnd,$nTicks)=@_;
   $nTicks//=5;
   my $axisWidth=$axisEnd-$axisStart;
   return undef unless $axisWidth>0;  # error is start >= end 
   
   my $niceRange=niceNumber($axisWidth,0);
   my $niceTick =niceNumber($niceRange/($nTicks-1) , 1);  
   $axisStart=floor($axisStart/$niceTick)*$niceTick;
   $axisEnd = ceil($axisEnd/$niceTick)*$niceTick;
   return ($axisStart,$axisEnd,$niceTick)  
}

# uesps algorthm
sub niceNumber{
  my ($value,$round)=@_;
 
  my $exp= floor(log($value)/log(10));
  my $fraction=$value/(10**$exp);
  
    if ($round){
       for ($fraction){
         $_ < 1.5  && return  1*(10**$exp);
         $_ < 3.0  && return  2*(10**$exp);
         $_ < 7.0  && return  5*(10**$exp);
         return  10*(10**$exp);
       }
    }
    else{
       for ($fraction){
         $_ < 1  && return  1*(10**$exp);
         $_ < 2  && return  2*(10**$exp);
         $_ < 5  && return  5*(10**$exp);
         return  10*(10**$exp);
       }
    }
}


# saves having to use POSIX
sub floor{
  my $v=shift;
  return int($v)-($v<0?1:0);
}

# saves having to use POSIX
sub ceil{
  my $v=shift;
  return int($v)+ ($v==int($v)?0:1);
}
```