# Scatter plot in matplotlib origin aligned

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've looked all over the net for this incredibly simple thing and can't find it.

I have a list of (x,y) points and want to plot them, with the origin in the lower left, grid marks showing 0,1,2,3,4... on each axis, and orange dots. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly basic, you should look a bit around in the matplotlib documentation, the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) or [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) section shows a lot of different stuff and the code that generated it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Random sample data
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, 10)
y = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, 10)

plt.scatter(x,y, c='orange')
plt.ylim([0, y.max()])
plt.xlim([0, x.max()])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494232/how-to-add-constant-spaced-ticks-on-axes-whose-lenghts-vary-python

Comment: already figured it out but thanks, i used plt.xticks and plt.yticks